# Sticky Navigation and mobile responsive

Tags: html, css, menu, navbar, fixed

I am trying to use Sticky Navigation like this:  https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_navbar_sticky

but also make it mobile response like this: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_topnav

***Thank you in advance for your reply...***

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}

function myFunction2() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky")
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.header {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

#navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

#navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

#navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

#navbar a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.content {
  padding: 16px;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.sticky + .content {
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.navbar .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .navbar a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .navbar a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .navbar.responsive {position: relative;}
  .navbar.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .navbar.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<div class="header">
  <h2>Scroll Down</h2>
  <p>Scroll down to see the sticky effect.</p>
</div>

<div class="navbar" id="mynavbar">
  <a class="active" href="javascript:void(0)">Home</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)">News</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)">Contact</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <h3>Sticky Navigation Example</h3>
  <p>The navbar will stick to the top when you reach its scroll position.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this simply using jquery, see below code.
Took offset of the div till navbar need to be static, then it will be sticky.

```js
var fixmeTop = $('div#mynavbar').offset().top; 
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop(); // get current position

    if (currentScroll >= fixmeTop) {       // apply position: fixed if you
        $('div#mynavbar').css({         // scroll to that element or below it
            position: 'fixed',
            top: '0',
            left: '0'
        });
    } else {                                   // apply position: static
        $('div#mynavbar').css({          // if you scroll above it
            position: 'static'
        });
    }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.header {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

#navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

#navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

#navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

#navbar a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.content {
  padding: 16px;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.sticky + .content {
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.navbar .icon {
  display: none;
}
div#mynavbar {
  width: 100%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .navbar a:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) {display: none;}
  .navbar a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .navbar.responsive {position: relative;}
  .navbar.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .navbar.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="header">
  <h2>Scroll Down</h2>
  <p>Scroll down to see the sticky effect.</p>
</div>

<div class="navbar" id="mynavbar">
  <a class="active" href="javascript:void(0)">Home</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)">News</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)">Contact</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <h3>Sticky Navigation Example</h3>
  <p>The navbar will stick to the top when you reach its scroll position.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This does make it sticky, but the menu is not responsive responsive like https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_topnav

Comment: Added css for max-width:600px; bars icon display block, included font-awesome library that you used. Check now...

Comment: Thank you  ElusiveCoder

Comment: I got this error... {
  "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 131,
  "colno": 71
}